# ERROR 1142 (42000): ALTER command denied

Tags: mysql

I have strange behavior on my MySQL server. I'm sure I have an account with all privileges. Here's the proof :

```
mysql> show grants;

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for ***@localhost                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '***'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '***'    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `***`.* TO '***'@'localhost'                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `***`.* TO '***'@'localhost'                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `***`.* TO '***'@'localhost'                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

but why I always get error message when I'm executing this syntax :

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE outbox_multipart.ID AUTO_INCREMENT = 12;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    13924219
Current database: ***

ERROR 1142 (42000): ALTER command denied to user '***'@'localhost' for table 'ID'
```

I can do almost everything (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, etc) but ALTER with that account. any idea what's wrong with it?

I tried to do same thing with phpmyadmin and php script, but got same result. seems that I can't ALTER that column.

Comment: error messages don't lie, are you altering on remote machine?

Comment: remote machine? no. I'm using phpmyadmin on my cPanel and it failed. then I tried to use SSH and have same result. so basically, I'm not on remote machine. I'm on localhost (from server point-of-view).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User `'***'@'localhost'` has all privileges on database `'***'`, but you are trying to ALTER table in another database - `outbox_multipart`. Add privileges to this database, re-connect and try to ALTER.

Comment: you're right. I have wrong syntax to alter. the correct one is this : ALTER TABLE outbox_multipart AUTO_INCREMENT = $rowLastID

Answer (score 0):

After granting commands you should run command as root

```
flush privileges;
```

after that your grant will be valid.